# Call constructor init from another constructor with shared objects in their arguments

Tags: java, constructor

So, I have a class with the following constructors:

```
public SomeClass() {
    this.foo = new Foo();
    this.bar = new Bar(foo); // Bar construction requires foo
}

public SomeClass(Foo foo, Bar bar) {
    this.foo = foo;
    this.bar = bar;
}
```

Now, I would like to reutilize the second constructor by changing the default constructor for something like:

```
public SomeClass() {
    Foo = new Foo();
    this(foo, new Bar(foo));
}
```

But this doesn't work as I'm getting

```
Error:(24, 21) java: call to this must be first statement in constructor
```

Note that I don't want to have 2 separate instances of foo.

Any ideas how to solve this scenario?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to use a `this` constructor, it must be the first line of the constructor. Something like,

```
public SomeClass() {
    this(new Foo());
}

public SomeClass(Foo foo) {
    this(foo, new Bar(foo));
}
```

**Note**: You can make the `SomeClass(Foo)` constructor `private` if you want to prevent outside calls.

Comment: oohhh I see your point. You are saying that I should add an intermediate constructor, right??

Comment: @jscherman Should implies a recommendation, in my own opinion there was nothing wrong with your initial approach; however, if you want to delegate to another constructor this is one way you can. It does not have to be `public` (as I noted), if you make it `private` then only `SomeClass` can access it.